# Multiple IF Statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have a column ExpireDate and am trying to return an end of the month date based on the created date is less or equal than the 10th of the month will return the last day of the month, if is greater than the 10th of the month will return the last day of the following month.

e.g. Created is 05/02/21 would return ExpireDate 28/02/21, however if created is 11/02/21 (or onwards) would return ExpireDate 31/03/21

With this in mind I have 3 formula that are working but I would like to combine them to have only one column.

The first formula will return the 10th of the month:

```
=DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),10)
```

The second formula will return the last day of the current month:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1)-1
```

The third formula returns the last day of the month based on todays date

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+2,1)-1
```

I tried the below to combine the formulas but have hit a brick wall

```
IF[Created]=>DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),10), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1)-1, =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+2,1)-1
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
=IF(DAY(Created)<11,DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created)+1,0),DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created)+2,0))
```

Return data type of calculated field as Date and Time (You can find this option below formula textbox)

Comment: Make sure to set your calculated field value to be a Time and Date data type.

Comment: Thanks, That solved my issue!!